# Error installing norGIS ALKIS Importer package with OSGeo4W

Tags: import, xml, osgeo4w

I am trying to import ALKIS NAS Data (XML) in QGis. These are german test cadaster datas. I already created a PostGIS database where I can import the XML with the nor GIS ALKIS importer. This will be later imported into QGis.
When installing the installing norGIS ALKIS Importer package (called: ALKIS-import:norGIS ALKIS import GeoInfoDoc 6.0) with OSGeo4W advanced Install I get the following error:

> Invalid or unsupported tar format.

[image: Invalid or Unsupported tar format]

I have never worked with similar data.